# Playing live streams directly from web page?

Tags: applications

do you know is there any way to watch VLC streams from my android phone (nexus 5)? I found several pages that provide streams directly (e.g. http://www.gletvuzivo.pw/2015/02/rtl-2-uzivo-stream.html) and in this example you can see that first two tabs require x-google-vlc-plugin to play the stream. I can use the link with flash player but I'd prefer to watch them via VLC (either VLC player for android or directly from web page).

Is this even possible?

I'd like to thank anyone in front for the answer.

Regards, Yowitza

Answer (score 0):

i think MX player is better than VLC so you can try Live Streams

or for VLC

Open Chrome web browser, browse to chrome://plugins
Now, you will see an option, “VLC Web Plugin”. If this line is available, you have successfully installed the VLC player plugin for Chrome.